# Is there a mininal, command-line-only distribution of Ubuntu or similar that runs within MS Windows

Tags: windows

I'm looking for a distribution of Linux (hopefully similar to or based upon Ubuntu) which satisfies the following criteria:

- Installs from and runs within Windows;
- Doesn't need to partition or dual-boot;
- Boots to a shell within Windows.

Ideally I'd like to click a shortcut on the Windows desktop and have a Linux shell appear in a command-prompt-style window. Obviously performance is unimportant since I assume a filesystem-within-a-filesystem is going to be slow.

I've found distros like PortableUbuntu and PenDriveLinux, but they all seem to be either out-of-date, minimally-supported, or too large.

Is there anything like that out there?

Comment: You need to run server in a virtual box.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might find that something like [coLinux](http://www.colinux.org/) or [andLinux](http://www.andlinux.org/) might be slightly lighter but personally, I'd choose a VirtualPC/VirtualBox/VMWare virtual machine every time.

The problem with the xming-style native builds of Linux distributions is they're very non-standard. They're hacks to serve a purpose. They might fit your purpose but I prefer to have standard things available. With a VM  you can port to a proper bare-metal install if the need ever arises.

Answer (score 7):

If you are only looking to run some Linux commands, you may want to try [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) . Cygwin, it is a Unix/Linux environment for Windows that can be used to have all that tools that windows lacks: bash, sed, awk, grep, vi, tail, ps, and many more. Once installed it will provide a shortcut that opens a terminal with a bash prompt. It also has an X-server environment if you need it. I've been using it for a few years now and it makes my live easier in Windows.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds to me like you should look into [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/) - as for a "minimal, command-line-only distribution", take a look at [Ubuntu Server](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/download).

Comment: VMWare is an option certainly, and a server version is exactly what I had in mind... just wondered whether there was a hybrid system out there.

Comment: As for interfacing with it, Ubuntu server will present a command line through VMWare/Virtualbox's interface or you can install a SSH server on Ubuntu and use Putty

Answer (score 1):

This answer is very late, but I feel it's worth replying for anyone who stumbles across this via a web search, as I did.

Windows now has [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) (versions 1803 and above), and [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/Microsoft/Terminal) (1903 and above). These introduce native support for running Linux programs on Windows.

Available distros include Ubuntu 18.04, among others.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a full environment, use the Ubuntu [MinimalCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) (which weighs in at < 40MB).

If you just want the basics of a Bash Shell without the rest of the environment, [Git Bash](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?q=label%3aFeatured) should get you most of the way there.